# Почему WordPress 5.5.3 c PHP 8 выдаёт 404 на каждой странице сайта?

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress в последней на настоящий момент версии 5.5.3 при попытке включить только что выпущенный PHP 8 выдаёт 404 ошибку. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Официально WordPress будет совместим с PHP 8 только начиная с версии 5.6, которая запланирована на 8 декабря 2020. RC-версия ядра WordPress 5.6 работает правильно с PHP 8, проблема устранена. Однако интересно разобраться, что является источником проблемы.

Для начала попробуем ответить на вопрос, а чему равно значение выражения

```
'' < 0
```

(пустая строка меньше нуля)?

Первый ответ, который приходит в голову, это `false`. Пустая строка приводится к нулю, идёт сравнение `0 < 0`, результат `false`.

Так было всегда в PHP, и до PHP 8, результат выражения - `false`. Но не в PHP 8. Здесь результат выражения - `true`, и это [официально объявлено](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/ru.php#saner-string-to-number-comparisons). При сравнении с числовой строкой используется сравнение чисел. Но пустая строка - не числовая, и PHP 8 использует сравнение строк: `'' < '0'`, и результат - `true`.

Какое отношение это имеет к WordPress?

В ядре есть метод, который вызывается при каждом запросе: `\WP_Query::parse_query`. В нём строки

```
if ( ! is_scalar( $qv['p'] ) || $qv['p'] < 0 ) {
    $qv['p']     = 0;
    $qv['error'] = '404';
    ...
```

В большинстве случаев `$qv['p']` содержит пустую строку, что приводит к срабатыванию `if` и установке ошибки 404.

В версии WordPress 5.6 строка сравнения выглядит так:

```
if ( ! is_scalar( $qv['p'] ) || (int) $qv['p'] < 0 ) {
```

что устраняет проблему в PHP 8 и работает корректно во всех версиях PHP.

Резюме: не стоит полагаться на неявное приведение типов, особенно при разработке кода, который планируется использовать под PHP 8.

[Источник](https://kagg.eu/why-wordpress-5-5-3-with-php-8-shows-404-on-every-page/)